# Validating an entry in TK/Tcl

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

I am trying the validate the text input of an entry.

```
entry $w.e -validate key -vcmd "entryChanged $w.l $w.e"
```

I have the following callback defined.

```
proc entryChanged {l e} {
    puts [$e get]
    return 1
}
```

The problem is that get returns the previous value of the entry as the new value isn't set until after the validation. My question is how do I access the new value? (value to be validated) I believe it has something to do with `-textvariable`, however, I can't find much documentation on this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll want to have a good read through the Validation section of the [`entry` documentation](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TkCmd/entry.htm). For example, try this

```
... -vcmd {entryChanged  %W %s %P}

proc entryChanged {widget_name old_value new_value} {
    puts "widget name = $widget_name"
    puts "previous value = $old_value"
    puts "edited value = $new_value"
    return true
}
```